# Tag for constraint theory

Tags: feature-request

I was wondering whether there are any tags for the following thing:

Constrained thinking, under constrained, language. (and, constrained considerations).

For example, this field, of science, focuses on what problems you may think about, and, can be solved, under constrained thinking, constrained language, and constrained considerations.

It sheds light into as a side effect how discoveries are made, when some information or things you can do are not available.

The discoveries can be accompanied by a proof that the discovery can be carried out under constraint.

For example, you may not have some things, and use what you have to carry out your task, but are not allowed to think about.

For example, if a user is allowed to use money, but not sex or food to carry out their thinking, they may do so, and prove that their thought was only related to money, and, not food, or sex.

Thank you.

Comment: Of course, the more you don't do, the more you can write.

Comment: I'd guess the tag ([meta-tag:tags]) would be suitable here.